# display hidden divs when another div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I am currently try create a custom navigation on websites homepage that uses tiles for navigation.

I am using MVCSiteMapProvider for MVC5 to display live tiles on the homepage as well as a standard bootstrap navbar, when the user loads the homepage only the main parent navigation any values nested under the parent are hidden.

The CSHTML below is what I have managed to create so far:

```
 <section id="content">
    <div class="main-content">
        @{
            var nodes = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;
        }

        @foreach (var node in nodes.RootNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 live-tile" id="@node.Key">
                <div class="@node.Description">
                    <h3>@node.Title</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            foreach (var childNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden @childNode.ParentNode.Key">
                    <div class="@childNode.Description">
                        <h3>@childNode.Title</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</section>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.live-tile').on('click', function () {
        var ids = $('.live-tile').map(function () {
            return this.id;
        }).get();
        $.each(ids, function (index, value) {
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need some guidance on how to display multiple divs when one of the parent tiles (div) is clicked.

I only want to show the child elements, currently I am try to do this using the id of the parent div as a class on it child elements, when the parent is clicked the other top level divs should be hidden and the child elements and parent should be visible.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 live-tile" id="@node.Key">
    <div class="@node.Description">
      <h3>@node.Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 hidden @childNode.ParentNode.Key">
    <div class="@childNode.Description">
      <h3>@childNode.Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 hidden @childNode.ParentNode.Key">
    <div class="@childNode.Description">
      <h3>@childNode.Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 hidden @childNode.ParentNode.Key">
    <div class="@childNode.Description">
      <h3>@childNode.Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="col-md-4 live-tile" id="@node.Key">
    <div class="@node.Description">
      <h3>@node.Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 hidden @childNode.ParentNode.Key">
    <div class="@childNode.Description">
      <h3>@childNode.Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 hidden @childNode.ParentNode.Key">
    <div class="@childNode.Description">
      <h3>@childNode.Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 hidden @childNode.ParentNode.Key">
    <div class="@childNode.Description">
      <h3>@childNode.Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

```
$('.live-tile').on('click', function () {
  $('.main-content>div').not('.live-tile').addClass('hidden');// hide all divs on click
  $('.main-content>div').removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  $('.clicked').nextUntil( '.live-tile', "div.hidden" ).removeClass('hidden');// now show the next hidden ones
});
```

Comment: hi Luke this disables all the divs but does not seem to show the hidden divs, any ideas?

Comment: sorry to be nuisance, but any ideas on how I can modify your jquery so that all but the div clicked are also hidden and only hidden div with the parent id in their class are shown